# Hibernate Search Lucene query parser with Special Characters

Tags: java, search, lucene, special-characters, hibernate-search

**FIRST QUESTION:**
Can somebody explain to me how the lucene query in Hibernate Search handles special characters. I read the documentation about [Hibernate search](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-building-lucene-queries) and also the [Lucene Regexp Syntax](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_5_5/core/org/apache/lucene/util/automaton/RegExp.html#RegExp(java.lang.String)) but somehow they don't add up with the generated Queries and Results.

Lets assume i have following database entries:

| name |
| --- |
| Will |
| Will Smith |
| Will - Smith |
| Will-Smith |

and i am using following Query:

```
Query query = queryBuilder  
    .keyword()           
    .onField("firstName")
    .matching(input)
    .createQuery();
```

Now I am looking for the following input:

Will -> returns all 4 entries, with the following generated query: FullTextQueryImpl(firstName:will)

Will Smith -> also returns all 4 entries with the following generated query: FullTextQueryImpl(firstName:will firstName:smith)

Will - Smith -> also returns all 4 entries with the following generated query: FullTextQueryImpl(firstName:will firstName:smith) ? Where is the "-" or shouldn't it forbid everything after the "-" according to [Lucene Query Syntax](https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html#-)?

Will-Smith -> same here

Will-Smith -> here i tried to use backslash but same result

Will -Smith -> Same here

**SECOND QUESTION:** Lets assume i have following database entries in which the entry without numerical ending always exists and the ones with numerical ending could be in the datebase.
How woul a lucene query for this look like?

| name |
| --- |
| Will |
| Will1 |
| Will2 |

Comment: Can you provide some clarifications? (1) Which version of Lucene are you using? or, if it's easier, which version of Hibernate Search? (2) I'm not sure what you mean by the way you have shown your searches. For example, in `Will - Smith ->`, what does that arrow `->` mean? (3) I am not sure what you mean by "where is the - ...?" Do you mean where is it in the results? Or where do you need to place it in the query? It's a bit hard to know where you are getting stuck.

Comment: (4) Have you provided a custom analyzer? If so, what are the details? (5) What annotations are you using on your entity and on your firstName field? (6) Are you always using `.keyword()` for all your queries? All of these points can affect how your data is indexed, and what results your queries return, so it may be easier to help if we can see all of these details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can play around with Lucene analyzers and see what happens behind the scenes. Here is a tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/lucene-analyzers

The tokenizer is pluggable, so you can change how special characters are treated.